# Providing API Keys at Runtime for Chromium doesn't work

Tags: macos, environment-variables, chromium

I installed Chromium for mac OS X.
When I launched the browser, I got a message stating "Google api keys are missing".
I followed the [instructions](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys) on the "Chromium developers how-to". I have configured the needed API and got my API Credentials.
Then, I followed the instructions under the section of "Providing Keys at Runtime".

It seems like my attempts didn't work:

- In order to add the variables into system's environment variables, I used the the command
   `echo "GOOGLE_API_KEY=my_api_key" >> .bash_profile`
   and then `source .bash_profile`. 
  I did that to each variable stated in the document.
- In order to check if the variabes were ser properly, I checked the .bash_profile file by using the command `less .bash_profile` and by the command `printenv` and the variables appear there.
- I also did a restart to the computer, thinking it might be needed for those action to have an effect.
- After I saw that didn't work, I tried adding the variables into system's environment variables by using the command `nano .bash_profile` - editing the file visually via the terminal and then saving the changes (although the previous changes did appear, I tried to delete them and then add them once again through *this method*).

I'm not sure what went wrong in that process, it seems like the API Keys are set properly as environment variables and yet chromium doesn't recognise them.

I would like to know what I should further do in order to solve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands in your bash profile are only run if you start `bash`, and are only then available in a `bash` shell or its child processes. Since your environment variables are only available to `bash`, you need to start Chrome from `bash`.

First, open your `.bash_profile` in `nano` again and add the word `export` to the start of each line (e.g. `export GOOGLE_DEFAU`…). This will make child processes of the shell inherit the environment variables. Then, close and reopen your Terminal to reload your `.bash_profile`.

To launch Chromium from `bash` in the Terminal, just run something of this form (location of your build may vary):

```
/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked.
After launching chromium from bash, does it then acknowledge the environment variables for every session? Do I need to keep launching it from the terminal or it's just that I needed to do it once and from now on I'm able to launch it via spotlight and the dock?

Comment: You'll have to launch from `bash`. However, you can make a script with the extension `.command` that'll be double-clickable in the Finder (e.g. https://gist.github.com/davidschlachter/0ff9b0119cf5d8ef05acca9f8f429cab ). Just be sure to make it executable (`chmod a+x /the/script.command`).